# MATLAB: how to pass in the diagonal of a matrix as an argument in another matrix?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Let `c` be 2D array, and `x` and `y` be 1D arrays of the same length (for instance, let's have `x=1:7` and `y=3:9`).

I need to find a way to pass in arguments from `x` and `y` in the way I will describe below.

If I put simply `c(x,y)` it will give a 7 by 7 matrix. I don't want that.
Instead, I want to pass in the diagonal of the `[x y]` matrix: `((x(1), y(1)), (x(2), y(2))...(x(7), y(7))`. Is there a way to do this without a for loop or any iterative statement?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) function

```
res = c( sub2ind(size(c), x, y ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an easier way. If you're looking for a diagonal, use [`diag`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diag.html). If you have a matrix `c`:

```
c =

    5    8    4    2    9    1    6    1    1
    9    8    7    5    9    3    2    7    5
    2    3    9   10    2    1    4    2    2
    3    2    9    2    4    4    7    2    4
    3    9   10    8    7    5    2    1    8
    5    6    3    7    6    1   10    5    2
    6    1    7    3   10    8    2    4    2
```

you can find the main diagonal by using `diag` with no extra arguments:

```
>> diag(c)
ans =

   5
   8
   9
   2
   7
   1
   2
```

The second argument, though, indicates *which* diagonal you want as an offset from the main diagonal. So the default diagonal is equal to `0`. If you want the diagonal starting at `c(1,3)`, that's `2` *above* the main diagonal, so

```
>> diag(c,2)
ans =

   4
   5
   2
   4
   2
   5
   2
```

Similarly, if you want the diagonal starting at `c(4,1)`, the offset is `-3`:

```
>> diag(c,-3)
ans =

   3
   9
   3
   3
```